# SharePoint: PNP people picker not showing suggestions

Tags: sharepoint, spfx, peoplepicker

When pnp people picker is used in SPFX, it is not giving suggestions.

Getting below error in network tab.

Microsoft.OData.Core.ODataException"

"A null value was found for the property named 'SharePointGroupID', which has the expected type 'Edm.Int32[Nullable=False]'. The expected type 'Edm.Int32[Nullable=False]' does not allow null values."

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in current version, You can try using beta. Full thread about it can be found here:

https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/issues/1292

Comment: Removing caret from version resolved the issue 

Changed "@pnp/spfx-controls-react": "^3.5.0" to "@pnp/spfx-controls-react": "3.5.0"

 Thank you Marcin!